# How to avoid duplicate blocks of code found in POJO classes?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am facing issue for SonarQube: Duplicate block of  code found in POJO classes even though I cannot find any duplicates in those classes. I also did not find anything in included classes as well.
Also we can see a vertical yellow/orange bar in the left margin. It marks the duplicate block, but in case these are not there.

Can somebody help to remove these issues from SonarQube?
If that is not possible to be fixed, how can we exclude these POJO class packages from SONAR rules?

Comment: Without seeing your actual code we can't help. Please post relevant code

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to be duplicated from other class as in both your `User` and `Category` may have same fields, same getter setter methods.

There should be some line for sure, may be of different color, clicking on that you can the the block it duplicates for.

*EDIT*
Disabling issues depends on the version you use, however it http://host:port/coding_rules#rule_key=common-java%3ADuplicatedBlocks. You will have to login as admin. It should be at Menu-> Rules. If you are logged in as admin, you will be able to see the option to de-activate.

However, I would say don't de-activate the rule. Instead mark the issue as "Resolve as won't fix". Again you will need to login as admin and click on "Open" status of the issue and do "Resolve as Won't fix". This helps removing other "actual" potential duplicates because disabling the issue will not show them.

Comment: Thanks Akshay! We have multimodule projects which are differntaited based on integrations layers. The POJO which we're using from host sytems, same kind of POJO's are being at REST controller level. So if this is the case, we cannot avoid it, we have to duplicate these fields. So coming to next point, can we exclude these model classes? if so, any pointers please?

Comment: Edited the answer